# How to combine two xpath

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I am new to XPath and I don't know if the title is right or not, but here is the question I want to make a XPath for a screen web scraper and these are the two HTML lines that I want to scrape

```html
<div class="pdp_featurelist_group cyc-typo_body-2">Einsatzzweck</div>
<div class="pdp_featurelist_value cyc-typo_body cyc-color-text_secondary">Trekking, Alltägliches Fahren, Commuting</div>
```

The goal is that scraper should match this text "Einsatzzweck" and then it should scrape the text in the second line "Trekking, Alltägliches Fahren, Commuting"

Comment: Well, try any XPath tutorial and give it a go, the second `div` is a sibling element so consider to use the `following-sibling` axis.

Comment: Thank for answering i have created a xpath something like this '//*[contains (text(),'Anzahl Gänge gesamt')]//following-sibling::div' the scraper is scraping the correctly but it is not working for the sub elements do you any solution for that.

Comment: Your description says you are looking for "Einsatzzweck", so I would assume you want e.g. `//div[.  = "Einsatzzweck"]/following-sibling::div[1]`. I am not sure what you are looking for when talking about "sub elements", it is not clear which version of XPath you use, which type of result  (a node like such a `div` element) or a string like "Trekking, Alltägliches Fahren, Commuting" you are looking for as the result. In XPath 1.0, if you want the string value as the result of the XPath evaluation, you can use `string(//div[.  = "Einsatzzweck"]/following-sibling::div[1])`.